# Safari displaying a single font at different weights on different pages though it has IDENTICAL CSS properties

Tags: html, css, safari, typography

I've got a font for a website that I'm loading via @font-face. However, in Safari, it shows up at different weights on different pages, *even though inspector shows all styles to be identical.*

I've tried setting the font-weights (and anything else I can think of) explicitly, but nothing seems to affect it.

You can see for yourself the variation below:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? or know how to fix it?

Comment: When possible, use http://JSFiddle.com to show a demonstration of your problem.

Comment: Post HTML and CSS code that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;`. This will force safari rendering method then safari will render the font using this method only, instead of automatically switching it.

I had this problem one time, when I implemented a CSS-only slideshow, and the site title rendered bolder when a specific image was shown.

<sub>Be aware of that some texts will look bad with this.</sub>